# trying to use inheritance varibles from another class in other file ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

FILE: bank.rb

```
class Bank
    def initialize ()
        @bank_name  = "Natinonal Bank"
        @saving = 1.85e123
        @found = "12/03/1933"
        @employee = {
            :it => ["Joah", "Carlos", "Roberto", "Luisa", "Anna", "Julio", "Marcos", "Guilherme"],
            :rh => ["João", "Marcos. F", "Richalison", "Agusto", "Ulisses", "Mariana", "Sarah"],
            :contabilidade => ["Julia", "José", "Henrique", "Marlon", "Messias", "Renato", "Luis"]
        }
        @sectors = [:it, :rh, :contabilidade]
    end

    def total_employees ()
        @employee.each {|key, value|
            counter = 0
            puts "No setor de #{key} consta-se os funcionários:"
            value.each {|func|
                puts "\t-->#{func}"
                counter += 1
            }

            puts "Total de funcionários no setor de #{key} é: #{counter}"
            puts "\n"
        }
    end

    def info ()
        puts "
    NOME >> #{@name}
    TOTAL SAVING >> #{@saving}
    ORIGEM >> #{@found}
        "
    end
end
```

FILE: fiscal.rb

```
require ".\\bank"

class Fiscal < Bank
    #attr_reader :user, :choice

    def initialize (user, choice)

        @user_name = user
        @choice_ = choice
        puts @user_name
        puts @bank_name
    end

    def do
        if @choice == 1
            puts @bank_name
            system "PAUSE"
            system "CLS"

        elsif @choice == 2
            info
            system "PAUSE"
            system "CLS"

        else
            system "CLS"
            puts "SAINDO"
            system "PAUSE"
        end
    end
end

if __FILE__ == $0
    puts "
[1] ---> Total de funcionários
[2] ---> Informações do banco
*Outros valores -> exit
-----------------------------------
    "
    puts "Informe nome, e a escolha"
    Bank.new
    fiscal_obj = Fiscal.new("Pedro", 1)
end
```

1.I'm trying to access @banlk_name from the class Bank, I tried to use super(bank_name) in the def initialize but it still doing some errors

--> I thought that if I did this it was supposedly going to work correctly
FILE: fiscal.rb

```
def initialize (user, choice, bank_name)
        super(bank_name)
        @user_name = user
        @choice_ = choice
        puts @user_name
        puts @bank_name
end
```

But the error still occuring, basicly I'm trying to see the varibles from the class Bank, but some error still on my code: puts @bank_name --> Nothing appears

Comment: Don't put a space between the method name and the parens. While it does not cause a syntax error like it would if you where calling a method with `foo (1, 2, 3)` its best avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You've inherited from the class correctly, but are then overwriting the method you're hoping to inherit from (or at least some of).

Try:

```
class Fiscal < Bank
  #attr_reader :user, :choice

  def initialize (user, choice)
    @user_name = user
    @choice_ = choice
    super  ## <--- Insert this line here
    puts @user_name
    puts @bank_name
  end
```

`Super` tells rails to execute the method that the class you're inheriting from implements. By putting it in the middle of a redefined method, we can capture that behaviour and add to it in the child class

Comment: I tried to do it, but, wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0) (ArgumentError)

Comment: The error said that 2 given, expected 0, but, my calling is like this: 
fiscal_obj = Fiscal.new "Pedro", 1

Comment: Look, i tried to do this:
```
def initialize (user, choice)
    @user_name = user
    @choice_ = choice
    obj = Bank.new
    obj.total_employees # I works, this line call the method from bank class
   puts @user_name
   puts @bank_name
 end
```